# Could SecureRandom produces predictable random sequence

Tags: java, random

I hava a SecureRandom generator using SHA1PRNG:

SecureRandom rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

Lets assume this rnd generates a sequence of randoms:

R1 , R2, R3, R4...

So my question is: if R1 is known by someone, can he infer the following R2, R3, R4..?? Since PRNG is deterministic algorithm.

Comment: or saying, if an attacker aquires value "Ri" and he knows we are using SecureRandom(PRNG), can he know the following value "Ri+1"?

Comment: The answer requires extensive analysis of the SHA1PRNG implementation and would involve many parameters, assuming it has been done. It is thus way too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You would also need to know the seed the `SecureRandom` was initialized with to predict the following values.